# Mercurial: Last version dynamic link

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way to provide stakeholders a URL that will retrieve always the last version of an specific artifact versioned with Mercurial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your'e running 'hgweb' there is -- use tip instead of the changeset node id (hash) in the URL.  So a URL like this:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/1c92524c37cd/CONTRIBUTORS

becomes
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/CONTRIBUTORS